Substituting a force with a reaction torque in a non-solid body

A beam is fixed to a wall to the left A to a free support at B and gets a load P at C.

The exercise is to calculate the reaction force at B and the deflection at C with elementary cases. They do this by calculating the inner torque at B, $M = PL/2$. By doing this, they can then replace the force P at C with a reaction torque $M_0$ at B, $M_0 = -PL/2$ and solve the exercise with an elementary case.

However, here arises a conceptual question.
Is the system A-B with a reaction torque in B equivalent to the initial system with a load P in C?
To me it seems that it is not, because if you look in another point, say $x = L/2$ ($x$ starts in A), the inner torque in the first case is: $M = PL - R_b L/2$
However, in the second case with the load P replaced by a reaction torque $M_0$ in B, I don't know how to calculate the inner torque in $x= L/2$, as I don't think you can move the reaction torque $M_0$ from B to $x = L/2$. Hence I must assume it's not the same, and that the systems are not equivalent.
Are the systems equivalent, or is the modified system just good enough, to solve the problem with elementary cases?
If the second is true, why do the elementary cases ignore the change in inner torque?

"Is the system A-B with a reaction torque in B" If the support at B is an ideal roller support, there is no reaction torque in B.

What's more, the problem is statically indeterminate.

Yes. Please read more carefully. The problem is statically indeterminate, hence the solution with elementary cases.

As a part of this solution with elementary cases, the force P gets substituted by a torque in B (however you might be right that this should not be regarded as a reaction torque). The question is whether this substitution changes the system or not.

I  don’t know what “the elementary case” means.

Anyway, you can find the steps to a solution to your exact problem here: https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Civil_Engineering/Structural_Analysis_(Udoeyo)/01%3A_Chapters/1.10%3A_Force_Method_of_Analysis_of_Indeterminate_Structures
